# Android custom lint rule does not detect any issue (for imports)

Tags: android, android-lint

I am applying the lint project as follows to a app module where there are issues but non of the issues are detected.

```
lintChecks project(':customlint')
```

**ImportsIssueRegistry.kt**

```
class ImportsIssueRegistry : IssueRegistry() {
    override val issues: List<Issue>
        get() = listOf(
            SyntheticImportIssue.ISSUE,
            AndroidLogImportIssue.ISSUE
        )

    override val api: Int
        get() = CURRENT_API
}
```

**customlint/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'


ext.lintVersion = '26.4.2'

dependencies {

    //noinspection DifferentStdlibGradleVersion
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:$lintVersion"
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:$lintVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    testImplementation "com.android.tools.lint:lint:$lintVersion"
    testImplementation "com.android.tools.lint:lint-tests:$lintVersion"
    testImplementation "com.android.tools:testutils:$lintVersion"
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

jar{
    manifest{
        attributes 'Lint-Registry-V2': '[package name].ImportsIssueRegistry'
    }
}
```

**What I tried?**

- Checking the gradle version? I have the latest version (3.4.2)
- Tried changing: `Lint-Registry` to `Lint-Registry-V2` in customlint module
- Also tried adding generated jar as following to the module's build.gradle : `lintChecks fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['customlint.jar'] )`

**Update:**

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/seriousfolks/android-custom-lint)

Someone please help.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to give your package name here:  '[package name].ImportsIssueRegistry'

Comment: @rohiththammaiah I have given it, please look at the linked repo.

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem ?

Comment: @alphaguy nope.

Comment: Possibly related to [Android Studio Dolphin+ not detecting custom lint rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74953582) After lots of upgrades to your sample, I managed to have the Lint warning show using Android Studio Flamingo Beta 3 and gradle-8.0-rc-2-bin

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but it was cause by a missing `apply plugin: 'kotlin'` in the `build.gradle` for the lint rules' `build.gradle`, which is **not** your problem.

But you might want to catch up with the latest version of the API, with [this video from ADS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCmJWOkjbM0). Google really should update their documentations

Some notable differences:

- declare registry in a resources file
- AGP 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `lintPublish project(':customlint')` instead of `lintChecks project(':customlint')`. At the time of writing, Google's sample is out of date.

Comment: appreciate trying to help, but it does not work. I updated the question and include the link the repo, you may take a look

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove any **jar / Lint-Registry** stuff

Have a look here:
https://github.com/tikurahul/lint-experiments

Copy the [NoisyDetector](https://github.com/tikurahul/lint-experiments/blob/master/lint/src/main/java/com/rahulrav/NoisyDetector.kt) to help check that your setup is correct.